# How to do this proof of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The proof example preceding the question seems a bit random to me, if someone could explain the proof I would understand all questions of the type

Let $A,B,C,D$ be arbitrary sets. Prove that: $$(A\times B)\cap (C\times D)=(A\times C)\cap (B\times D).$$

Thanks!

Comment: While I certainly agree with Mauro Allegranza's comments, this begs the question: in general, how do you attack such a problem.  Given 2 sets $S$ and $T$, you show that $S=T$ by showing that $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$.  So you choose a random element in the set on the LHS, and try to prove that this element is also in the set on the RHS.  In general, this is how you attack such problems.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think you shouldn't give hints if you don't know how to solve the problem. This statement turn out to be false, so "Double inclusion" is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A=B=\{1\}$ and $C=D=\{2\}$.

Then

$A\times B = \{(1,1)\}$

$C\times D = \{(2,2)\}$

so $(A\times B)\cap (C\times D) = \emptyset$

$A\times C = \{(1,2)\}$

$B\times D = \{(1,2)\}$

so $(A\times C)\cap (B\times D) = \{(1,2)\}$

The statement is false.